# Waste and Biproducts generated during eNRR

Tags: electrochemistry, nitrogen, electrocatalysis

I am currently reviewing electrocatalytic methods of fixing nitrogen through eNRR and thereby looking up methods coming up in recent literature. However, I need to know what sort of waste products are usually generated from such electrocatalytic pathways. Most of the existing literature deals with the detection of the fixed product and doesn't elaborate on the details of side products and wastes generated.

Any literature quantifying (or even naming the waste products) will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the answer is quite dependent on the process used. The category of eNRR includes a wide variety of processes. Can you specify which one you are interested in?